# Django Views "Page not found"

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a password change page and I want to land on another page after successfully changing my password, but my code is giving me a page "Page not found"

```
path(
    "passwordchange/",
    auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(
        template_name="user/passwordchange.html", 
        form_class=PasswordChangeForm, 
        success_url="/passwordchangedone/"
    ),
    name="passwordchange",
),

path(
    "passwordchangedone/",
    auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name="user/passwordchangedone.html"),
    name="passwordchangedone",
```

Comment: Please add full error traceback to your question.